# When casting Inflict Wounds through a familiar, can I reroll the attack roll using the Elven Accuracy feat if I have advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, familiars

If I have a familiar, I can cast [*Inflict Wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/inflict-wounds) through it, as per the description of [*Find Familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar):

> Your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell.

*Inflict Wounds* includes a melee spell attack. The rules for [spell attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AttackRolls) state (PHB p. 206) that:

> Your attack bonus with a spell attack equals your spellcasting ability modifier + your proficiency bonus.

The [Elven Accuracy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/elven-accuracy) feat (XGtE, p. 74) states that

> Whenever you have advantage on an attack roll using Dexterity, Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma, you can reroll one of the dice once.

The second person pronoun is used in both of these last two wordings.  So if the **caster's**, rather than the **familiar's**, spellcasting ability modifier and proficiency bonus are used for this melee spell attack, it seems to follow that, given advantage on the attack, a reroll would be available via Elven Accuracy (if the caster has that feat).  Is this the case?

Comment: Related: [Does a spell that requires an attack roll count as an “attack” for familiars?](/questions/60137/), [Dealing Hex damage when a familiar delivers a touch spell](/questions/161417)

Comment: Note that if you look at the hex question for reference that the top answer is not RAW, for a RAW answer look at pwi's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes you can!

The key is in your first quote.   You are still the one making the attack.  So you benefit from all your feats. The familiar is a part of you and does not hold its own agency when you are using this ability.

It is worth noting that a familiar cannot attack on it's own, as it cannot use the attack action. As seen in the spell description on p240 of the Player's Handbook.

"Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands. In Combat, it rolls its own Initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can't Attack, but it can take other Actions as normal."

Comment: Hi, how do you pair up the idea that "Your familiar acts independently of you" with the familiary having no sense of agency? Just because it cannot make an "attack"? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: You are 100% in control of your familiar.  It is an extension of you.  It does act indipendantly in terms of game mechanic, because it has its own initiative.  But that doesn't mean it has its own agency.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that but what would it mean if i did have its own agency? What's the difference?

Comment: It means it would not be under your control.  It would have free will.

Comment: Thanks, so what in the game has agency? All PCs and NPCs are managed by someone, be it a DM or player. Would a NPC/creature that does notthing but defends itself if attacked have "agency"? If so, I get why your wrote that the familiar doesn't in your answer. :)